# Product in an non-commutative group

Tags: group-theory

I apologize in advance if my question is stupid.

Let $G$ be a group, and $x_1, x_2,\dots,x_n$ a family of elements of $G$. If their product is equal to $e$ (neutral element), is it possible to show that for any permutation of these elements, the product is still equal to the neutral element?

(Of course this is evident if $G$ is commutative, I'd like to know for the noncommutative case).

I tried to do this by recurrence on the number of elements. The case $n=2$ is OK, put I can't show that $P(n)$ implies $P(n+1)$.

I can't find any help on the internet.
Thank in advance.

Comment: It is not true, check $G=S_3$ with $n=3$.

Comment: $(12)(23)(12)(23) = (132) \neq (12)(12)(23)(23) = \operatorname{id}$

Answer (score 3):

Not in general, No. Consider $S_3$
$$
(12)(23)(31)(32) = e
$$
but
$$
(23)(12)(31)(32) = (123)
$$
However, it is true if you permute the element "cyclically". ie. If $x_1x_2\ldots x_n = e$, then $x_n x_1 x_2\ldots x_{n-1} = e$. Can you see why?

Answer (score 2):

No.  Consider, for instance, the dihedral group $D_3$, the symmetries of a triangle.  Let $r$ be any reflection and $s$ any non-trivial rotation.  Then

$srsr=1$

but

$rrss=s^2\neq 1$.

Comment: By the way, you might be interested to notice that any group which does have your property is commutative, because $ghg^{-1}h^{-1}=gg^{-1}hh^{-1}=1$ for any $g,h$.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to all for the quick answers !
Prahlad I see why it works if the permutation is "cyclic" :
if $$x_1 x_2 ... x_n = e $$ then $$x_1 x_2...x_{n-1} = {x_n}^{-1} $$ and then $$x_n x_1...x_{n-1}=e$$
and by iteration $$x_k x_{k+1}...x_n x_0 x_1...x_{k-1}=e$$